# HMAC SHA1 how to write in rhino- js

Tags: javascript, rhino

I want to implement HMAC SHA1 in rhino javascript(only in rhino js not in simple js). Can anybody please help me with some working code. Thank you in advance

Comment: Look at the [Stanford Javascript Crypto Library](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) article.

Answer (score 0):

Rhino is a JavaScript engine written fully in Java, it allows us to use Java libraries inside scripts:

```
importClass(java.security.MessageDigest);

var md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
var sha1 = md.digest((new java.lang.String("abc")).getBytes());
```